# ns-2 TCP window_ and cwnd_ relation

Tags: tcp, ns2

I have a topology like this:

```
[bunch of TCP/Reno sources]<---->Router1<---->Router2<---->[bunch of TCPSinks]
```

there are 20 pairs of connections via those two routers.
for example with connection TCP1-Sink1 I have window_ set to 32, and then I run the simulation and plot values of cwnd_.

The issue is that cwnd_ is occasionally larger than window_,
for example if I set window_ to 5, I get this:
[image]

and in case of 30, this:
[image]

Why does this happen, and why does not cwnd_ drop when it exceeds window_ ?

here is the code that collects data

```
$ns at 0.5 "activateSources"
$ns at 1.5 "startRecordingWindow"
$ns at 20.0 "finish"

proc plotWindow {tcpSource file} {
  global ns
  set time 0.01
  set now [$ns now]
  set cwnd [$tcpSource set cwnd_]
  puts $file "$now $cwnd"


  $ns at [expr $now+$time] "plotWindow $tcpSource $file"   
}
```

Comment: Unknown simulation : Please upload the simulation file(s) to e.g. Dropbox, and post a **shared** link.

Comment: @KnudLarsen here it is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19YoUWvk2-KAhFBXf2dULcc2yDFKoDVJZ

Comment: Any ideas? Could it be a bug in ns-2 itself? seems like window_ bound just does not work at all @KnudLarsen

Comment: 1. »»window_ set to 32 (or 5)«« : Which file, and which line number has got this setting. 2. I cannot reproduce your plot.pdf .... Please edit your question to include OS name and version https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61480582/edit

Comment: Dear Knud, it is line 44; in fact, there is only one line with set window_, so you can make a search, to find it quickly; As far as plotting, I use Ubuntu 18.04.2, and gnuplot for plotting. Once simulation is completed, you should pass the gnu_plot file to gnuplot utility with following command `gnuplot gnu_plot`  to generate .pdf file  @KnudLarsen